# SQL Topological Sort

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am resolving to topologically sort a set of equations below. The more the equation is dependent on more variables, the greater the order number. In other words, the given equation cannot be evaluated unless the variable(s) on the right are evaluated first.
Could someone show the sample of implementation of sorting in t-sql

```
DECLARE @TopSort TABLE 
(
   Expression VARCHAR(2000)
  ,[Order] INT
);


INSERT INTO @TopSort VALUES ('SSS =  BBB + KKK + JJJ', null)
INSERT INTO @TopSort VALUES ('MMM = EEE + RRR + GGG', null)
INSERT INTO @TopSort VALUES ('KKK = BBB + CCC + AAA', null)
INSERT INTO @TopSort VALUES ('BBB = CCC + QQQ', null)
INSERT INTO @TopSort VALUES ('DDD = BBB + SSS + RRR + 34', null)
INSERT INTO @TopSort VALUES ('AAA = PPP + 21', null)
INSERT INTO @TopSort VALUES ('PPP = 8', null)
INSERT INTO @TopSort VALUES ('JJJ = EEE + HHH + PPP + AAA', null)
INSERT INTO @TopSort VALUES ('YYY = SSS + MMM + DDD', null)
INSERT INTO @TopSort VALUES ('GGG = PPP + EEE + 45', null)
INSERT INTO @TopSort VALUES ('HHH = 76', null)
INSERT INTO @TopSort VALUES ('CCC = RRR + MMM', null)
INSERT INTO @TopSort VALUES ('QQQ = MMM + JJJ + CCC', null) 
INSERT INTO @TopSort VALUES ('EEE = 23', null)
INSERT INTO @TopSort VALUES ('RRR = AAA + HHH + GGG + 56', null)
INSERT INTO @TopSort VALUES ('ZZZ = AAA+DDD+BBB', null)
```

Here is the expected output:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please avoid posting image. Use text instead. Please also include your attempted query

Comment: T-SQL is simply not the right tool for this. It has poor support for string processing and its sequential constructs have very poor performance. Implementing a set-based solution to parsing equations, representing them as a graph and then sorting them in T-SQL with a recursive algorithm is all possible in theory, but an exercise in needless suffering (and it likely wouldn't scale for large sets). Using any programming language of choice on the client side; a lot even have libraries ready to go for topological sorting.

Comment: Please define "topological sort".  We did not cover that in the days when I studied Topology.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Topological sorting has nothing to do with topology, aside from both deriving from the same Greek root -- it's a concept from graph theory. Consider each term `AAA` as a node in a graph, and each equation `CCC = RRR + MMM` as defining edges between these nodes (in this case from `RRR` to `CCC` and from `MMM` to `CCC`), then a topological sort of the resulting graph gives an ordering of the equations such that they can be evaluated from top to bottom without terms being undefined. There are simple algorithms that implement it, but they're not quite as simple in T-SQL.

Answer (score -1):

I am interpreting the question as:  You want to count the number of substrings in the expression that contain at least one character and consist only of characters and digits.  This will eliminate any operators.  The first value is common to everything, so it doesn't affect the ordering.

You can do this using `string_split()`:

```
select ts.*, x.*
from TopSort ts cross apply
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from string_split(ts.expression, ' ') s
      where s.value like '%[A-Z]%' and
            s.value NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z0-9]%' 
     ) x
order by x.cnt;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a6dc55414b70f5ce3c588c4cd6e30de7) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This is incorrect; the end result is not a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). The equation `BBB = CCC + QQQ` cannot be evaluated before `CCC` and `QQQ` are evaluated, for example, so it appearing in the result set before these won't work. Admittedly the OP's initial description of "the more the equation is dependent on more variables, the greater the order number" can be interpreted this way, but is only consistent with a topological sort if we include *indirect* dependencies.

Comment: @JeroenMostert . . . This answers the question that is being asked.

Comment: Sorry, my contention is that it does not. There is no reasonable interpretation of a "topological sort" where this answer would be correct, and indeed the results do not match up with the OP's expected output.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You are correct. The given equation cannot be evaluated unless the variables on the right are evaluated first